Reading config values from zookeeper
I want to read all my app configs in appliction.properties from the zookeeper node.
I have a zookeeper node and have written this class to fetch configs in spring boot:
 @Service
public class ZookeeperService implements Watcher {

    @Value("${zookeeper.address}")
    private String zookeeperAddress;

    @Value("${zookeeper.port}")
    private int zookeeperPort;

    @Value("${zookeeper.path}")
    private String zookeeperPath;

    @Value("${secret.key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${zookeeper.username}")
    private String zookeeperUsername;

    @Value("${zookeeper.password}")
    private String zookeeperPassword;

    private ZooKeeper zooKeeper;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        zooKeeper = new ZooKeeper(zookeeperAddress + ":" + zookeeperPort, 3000, this);
        zooKeeper.addAuthInfo("digest", (zookeeperUsername + ":" + zookeeperPassword).getBytes());
        watchPath(zookeeperPath);
    }

    private void watchPath(String path) throws Exception {
        Stat stat = zooKeeper.exists(path, true);
        if (stat != null) {
            byte[] data = zooKeeper.getData(path, true, stat);
            processNodeData(new String(data));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void process(WatchedEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == Event.EventType.NodeDataChanged) {
            try {
                watchPath(zookeeperPath);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void processNodeData(String data) throws Exception {
        String[] lines = data.split("\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line.startsWith("PASSWORD=")) {
                String encryptedPassword = line.split("=")[1];
                if (encryptedPassword.startsWith("devEnc:")) {
                    String encryptedValue = encryptedPassword.substring("devEnc:".length());
                    String decryptedPassword = AESDecryptor.decrypt(encryptedValue, secretKey);
                    logToFile("Decrypted Password: " + decryptedPassword);
                }
            } else {
                logToFile(line);
            }
        }
    }

    private void logToFile(String message) {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("zkwatch.log", true)) {
            writer.write(message + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

But when I ran the application, I got an error for my placeholder configs because the application executes other classes and creates other beans before loading the configs from Zookeeper.
how can I make sure config values are going to be loaded first?
